# set checked item on top

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

```
foreac(abc.xyz entry in tlist)
{    
@{
   List<abc.Models.dian> dianobjlist = abc.Service.Class1.dianlist();

  }
     @foreach (abc.Models.dian dianobj in dianobjlist)
     { 
     <div class="dian">
     @if (dianobj.dian1 == entry.dian1)
     {
     <input type="checkbox" value='@dianobj.dian1' name="dianl" checked="checked"/>
     }
     else if (dianobj.dian1 == entry.dian2)
     {
     <input type="checkbox" value='@dianobj.dian1' name="dianl" checked="checked"/>
     }
     else if (dianobj.dian1 == entry.dian3)
     {
     <input type="checkbox" value='@dianobj.dian1' name="dianl" checked="checked"/>
     }
     else if (dianobj.dian1 == entry.dian4)
     {
     <input type="checkbox" value='@dianobj.dian1' name="dianl" checked="checked"/>
     }
     else
     {
      <input type="checkbox" value='@dianobj.dian1' name="dianl"/>
     }
     <label>@dianobj.dian1</label>
      </div>
  }
}
```

this is the code I have written to checked all those checkbox whose value satisfy if condition. Now,I want to the things is that all thos istems whose are checked should apper on top. We have more that 50 dian in our list but can be checked maximum 4 as per coding. All those items which are checked should be appear on the top and all unchecked items should appear below

Comment: What does `abc.Models.dian` look like? Is there any property in that object that tracks if it is checked?

Comment: dian is my table name, abc is my projct name, models is model in which .edmx file is stored

Answer (score 0):

You can order your list by whether or not they match your criteria (and will therefore be checked).

so you could replace your second `foreach` with the following:

```
@foreach (abc.Models.dian dianobj in dianobjlist.OrderBy(d => 
    d.dian1 == entry.dian1 || 
    d.dian1 == entry.dian2 || 
    d.dian1 == entry.dian3 ||
    d.dian1 == entry.dian4))
{
    // print out your inputs
}
```

ideally I think you would want to move the logic for deciding whether to check it or not into your class like so:

```
public class dian
{
    public bool IsCheckBoxChecked(abc.xyz entry)
    {
        return
            this.dian1 == entry.dian1 ||
            this.dian1 == entry.dian2 ||
            this.dian1 == entry.dian3 ||
            this.dian1 == entry.dian4;
    }
}
```

then you could simplify your view to be:

```
@foreach(abc.xyz entry in tlist)
{
    List<abc.Models.dian> dianobjlist = abs.Service.Class1.dianlist();

    foreach (abc.Models.dian dianobj in dianobjlist.OrderByDescending(d => d.IsCheckBoxChecked(entry)))
    {
        <div class="dian">
            @if(dianobj.IsCheckBoxChecked(entry))
            {
                <input type="checkbox" value='@dianobj.dian1' name="dianl" checked="checked"/>
            }
            else
            {
                <input type="checkbox" value='@dianobj.dian1' name="dianl"/>
            }
            <label>@dianobj.dian1</label>
        </div>
    }
}
```